# Can I have Xcode 7 beta and Xcode 6 installed on one Mac computer

Tags: ios, xcode6, xcode7

So I want to install Xcode 7 beta to test some features, but my question is:

will it cause some problem with Xcode 6 and how to have 2 Xcodes on one machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: YES. You can install more than one versions of Xcode. I have 3 versions installed on my machine and never faced any problem. Just rename the newer ones so that you are not confused while launching.

Comment: seems there is an issue right now. I am trying to debug sources in Xcode 6, but when I get a line where I put breakpoint Xcode 6 unexpectedly crashes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, the diffrent versions are installed in diffrent directorys.

Answer (score 1):

YES. you can install different versions of Xcode on your machine. I have Xcode 6, Xcode 7b5, Xcode 7b6 installed. You can download the release version of Xcode 6 from App Store and the beta versions from the developer portal.

Answer (score -2):

Yes you can.

Here's a Shakshuka receipe:

Heat oven to 375 degrees.

Heat oil in a large skillet over medium-low heat. Add onion and bell pepper. Cook gently until very soft, about 20 minutes. Add garlic and cook until tender, 1 to 2 minutes; stir in cumin, paprika and cayenne, and cook 1 minute. Pour in tomatoes and season with 3/4 teaspoon salt and 1/4 teaspoon pepper; simmer until tomatoes have thickened, about 10 minutes. Stir in crumbled feta.

Gently crack eggs into skillet over tomatoes. Season with salt and pepper. Transfer skillet to oven and bake until eggs are just set, 7 to 10 minutes. Sprinkle with cilantro and serve with hot sauce.

Comment: haha) nice! I don't know why someone does not like your answer. Looks funny )))

Comment: @MatrosovAlexander Yes indeed. Answering with a plain 'yes' is boring. This question needs a plain 'yes', so I decided to flavor it up with a shakshuka receipt! good luck!

Comment: I am afraid of moderators otherwise I would have up voted your answer. It is better than mine :)